# Getting a basic JavaScript code to work

Tags: javascript

I recently started a new project, so at the moment it is quite simple code. I think there is probably just and error or something I am unaware of that is causing an issue. To a more experienced programmer, this should be an easy fix. My HTML and JavaScript is

```js
var quotecount = 3;

function show() {
  var rand = Math.floor((Math.random() * quotecount) + 1);

  if (rand == 1) {
    document.getElementById("disp").innerHTML = "Quote 1";
    document.getElementById("quotenum").innerHTML = "This is quote 1 out of " + quotecount;
  }

  if (rand == 2) {
    document.getElementById("disp").innerHTML = "Quote 2";
    document.getElementById("quotenum").innerHTML = "This is quote 2 out of " + quotecount;
  }

  if (rand == 3) {
    document.getElementById("disp").innerHTML = "Quote 3";
    document.getElementById("quotenum").innerHTML = "This is quote 3 out of " + quotecount;
  }
}
```

```css
button {
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 5px 13px;
  outline:none;
  cursor:pointer;
}

button:hover {
  background: #282828;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <button id="quoteshow" onclick="show">Click me to show a quote!</button>

  <p id="disp"></p>
  <p id="quotenum"></p>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: @clabe45 It doesn't work. When I click the button, nothing happens.

Comment: Have you tried opening up the javascript console?

Comment: javascript belongs in a `<script>` tag and you should wait for DOM to load, actually call your function, remove the tickmark `\`` and read console errors

Comment: you are not calling function show()

Comment: The js is in a separate file. That's why i'm not sure what is wrong. It appears right to me

Comment: <button onclick='show()'>Click</button>

Comment: Oooh. Silly mistakes are the ones that get you. Thanks! If you want to put that in an answer I will accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add parenthesis to `show` in your `onclick` call in the element.

```
<button id="quoteshow" onclick="show()">Click me to show a quote!</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var quotecount = 3;

function show() {
  var rand = Math.floor((Math.random() * quotecount)) + 1;

    if (rand == 1) {
      document.getElementById("disp").innerHTML = "Quote 1";
      document.getElementById("quotenum").innerHTML = "This is quote 1 out of " + quotecount;
    }

    if (rand == 2) {
      document.getElementById("disp").innerHTML = "Quote 2";
      document.getElementById("quotenum").innerHTML = "This is quote 2 out of " + quotecount;
    }

    if (rand == 3) {
      document.getElementById("disp").innerHTML = "Quote 3";
      document.getElementById("quotenum").innerHTML = "This is quote 3 out of " + quotecount;
    }
}
```

```html
<p id="disp"></p>
<p id="quotenum"></p>

<button onclick="show()">Click me</button>
```

Add click button.